# How can I link to a specific tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am using a theme that has tabs (list items) that are only displayed when the class is "active". By clicking on a tab, it changes the tab's class to 'active' (li class="active"), and only displays the content in the 'active' tab.

If I wanted to link to a specific tab from a different page, how can I create a link (presumably via javascript) that will send you to the page, and change an elements class?

Here's the HTML for reference

```
<div class="q_tabs horizontal center" style="visibility: visible;">
        <ul class="tabs-nav"><li class="active"><a href="#tab-1428877498-1-88">First Tab</a></li><li class=""><a href="#tab-1428877498-2-39">Second tab</a></li><li class=""><a href="#tab-1428877529303-2-2">Third tab</a></li></ul>
<div class="tabs-container">

        <div id="tab-1428877498-1-88" class="tab-content" style="display: block;">

 <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <p>First tab text</p>

    </div> 
</div> 
        </div> 
        <div id="tab-1428877498-2-39" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">

<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <p>Second tab text</p>

    </div> 
</div> 
        </div> 
        <div id="tab-1428877529303-2-2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">

<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <p>Third tab text</p>

    </div> 
</div> 
        </div> </div>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, sadly, there is no way with only Javascript to open up a tab in a new page. Fortunately, there are a few way to transfer information within the URL.

## 1. Using the # symbol

### Send info within the URL without reloading the page.

For instance, `yoursite.com/yoursecondpage#yourtabselection` If you are to add the # plus the tab number, your page would not reload. With javascript, you could find the number using the [`.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property. This is the easier way to do it.

## 2. Using the ? symbol

### Send info within the URL with reloading the page.

For instance, `yoursite.com/yoursecondpage?tab=2` If you are to add `?tab=tabnum` to the end of the URL, your page would reload. With javascript, this method is a little bit harder to find. This is the harder way to do it.

### I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. Can you provide an example using the # symbol?

Answer (score -1):

how about you create a function that recive a tab id(as an argument) and it will show only that tab (as it also hides the others).

then if you want to link it from another page make sure to pass the id(of the tab) via the url so you'll be able to make a simple JS check if there is any request for a specific tab and then use the function (as I described before).

use jQuery it shouldn't take more then 5min'
good luck.